# dec2bin doesnt work as per expectation when called through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Excel has this function `dec2bin(num,places)` which works well. But when I use it in VBA, I get the result, but format gets off the hook if msb and following bits are 0.

I wish to obtain:

`0001` instead of `1`

`0101` instead of `101`

This I observe when I redirect it to the spreadsheet:

```
Range("I2").Value = Mid(y, 2, 3)
```

If I store it in a variable and try to access the bits I get it right, but it's no use if I can't put it in spreadsheet the above mentioned way.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: What are you doing now (show the code that calls dec2bin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sVal As String

    sVal = Application.Evaluate("=DEC2BIN(7, 4)")

    Debug.Print sVal
End Sub
```

Or if you do not want to hardcode the `Places` then use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sVal As String
    Dim nPlace  as Long

    nPlace = 4

    sVal = Application.Evaluate("=DEC2BIN(7," & nPlace & ")")

    Debug.Print sVal
End Sub
```

This will give you `0111` and not `111`

**EDIT**

If you want to output it to an excel cell then you have two options

**A)** Format the cell as text and then use

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sVal As String
    Dim nPlace As Long

    '~~> Number of places
    nPlace = 4

    sVal = Application.Evaluate("=DEC2BIN(7," & nPlace & ")")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = sVal
End Sub
```

Alternatively you could use `.Numberformat` to format the cell via code.

OR

**B)** Use `'` before inputting the data in Excel

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sVal As String
    Dim nPlace As Long

    '~~> Number of places
    nPlace = 4

    sVal = Application.Evaluate("=DEC2BIN(7," & nPlace & ")")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = "'" & sVal
End Sub
```